# TypeError: Argument 'x' has incorrect type (expected cupy.core.core.ndarray, got numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python-3.x, chainer, cupy

Executing the following minimal example in cupy.

```
import numpy, cupy, cupyx

print( cupyx.get_runtime_info() )

mydata = numpy.empty((3,), dtype='f')

#gpu = False
gpu = True
if not gpu:
    xp = numpy
else:
    xp = cupy

    mydata_like = xp.zeros_like(mydata)
```

in the following manner

```
(venv) user@ailx216:/work/sandbox$ CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1 python cupy_test.py
```

Gives me this error:

```
  File "chainer_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    mydata_like = xp.zeros_like(mydata)
/cupy/creation/basic.py", line 205, in zeros_like
    order, strides, memptr = _new_like_order_and_strides(a, dtype, order)
/cupy/creation/basic.py", line 35, in _new_like_order_and_strides
    order = chr(_update_order_char(a, ord(order)))
TypeError: Argument 'x' has incorrect type (expected cupy.core.core.ndarray, got numpy.ndarray)
```

The output of print( cupyx.get_runtime_info() ) is as below:

```
CuPy Version          : 6.2.0
CUDA Root             : /usr/local/cuda-9.1/
CUDA Build Version    : 9010
CUDA Driver Version   : 10000
CUDA Runtime Version  : 9010
cuDNN Build Version   : 7102
cuDNN Version         : 7102
NCCL Build Version    : 2115
NCCL Runtime Version  : (unknown)
```

How can I debug this ?

Comment: The issue is alluded to in this post: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/2100. But the discussion seems to have moved to a slack channel afterward. Which I cannot locate :(

Comment: Is the code you pasted correct? I can't find this line in the code: `mydata_like = xp.zeros_like(mydata)`

Comment: @niboshi my apologies. it was a copy error. Please check the snippet now.

Comment: What is there to debug?  `cupy.zeros_like` [takes a cupy array](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.zeros_like.html), not a numpy array.

Comment: my bad. mydata = numpy.empty((3,), dtype='f') => mydata = xp.empty((3,), dtype='f') fixed it. Gotta read the docs before posting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original posting had a silly error. Here is a minimal cupy test that works for me.
Thanks for your help.

```
import numpy, cupy, cupyx

print( cupyx.get_runtime_info() )


gpu = True
if not gpu:
    xp = numpy
else:
    xp = cupy

mydata = xp.empty((3,), dtype='f')    
mydata_like = xp.zeros_like(mydata)
```